# can logstash package individual log types into packages an scp them over to a central node?

Tags: linux, logging, unix, log-files, logstash

I am curious whether logstash only processes logs and streams them at the event/line level or can it package all apache access logs for example and send them over zipped up to a central node?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of get there through a combination of `file {}` outputs, and an `exec {}` output that runs on a schedule and calls a script to zip up and transfer the files created by the `file {}` output. I wouldn't call it out of the box, but you can do it.